# What dishes don't stain with heavy spices?

Tags: equipment, spices, cleaning, indian-cuisine

In most Indian cooking, there is a relatively high chance of staining the dinnerware (plates, serving bowls) due to the high turmeric content. Dinnerware made of metal don't stain, but the heavy spices do most other materials in after a few uses.

What kind of dinnerware could I go for which are unbreakable but look better than metal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plastic dishes in general will pick up stains, non-plastic dishes (enamelware, glass, or glazed ceramic) in my experience won't.

For stain resistance combined with durability, as you've identified, the best option is likely enamelware, you might try looking for attractive patterns, while the old-fashioned camp cookware that we have in our cupboard isn't very attractive, I'm finding some designs that look much better online, certainly as good or better than plastic dishes.

If you can't find enamelware that's attractive enough for your taste, tempered glass dishes, as Wayfaring Stranger suggests, are certainly a fairly durable option, another would be heavy plain white porcelain dishes, which I've found to be significantly more durable than typical stoneware dishes. They'll still shatter if dropped on concrete, but they're less likely to chip in normal everyday use.

Comment: The average made-in-china porcelain dinnerware at dollar store works ok for me.

Answer (score 3):

Anything is breakable, but [Corelle/Vitrelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corelle), a laminated tempered glass, is plenty tough. I've never seen it take a stain other than rust, which can be removed w acid. Turmeric shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I confirm this: I've served turmeric-heavy dishes in Corelle for years without a single stain.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the recommendations above, glazed high-fire porcelain or stoneware, as well as glass, will not pick up turmeric stains.  By "high-fire" I mean "fired to 2375F or above".  Example brands would be Noritake, Emile Henry, or Highland Stoneware, but many less expensive store brands from Macy's, Bed Bath and Beyond, and similar chains are also high-fire.  Many are not, though, so make sure to ask the store.

Such ceramics are also chip-resistant, usable in stove and microwave, and otherwise long-lasting, which is a nice bonus.